# Teradata Database and Eclipse/Java error: UPPERCASE or CASESPECIFIC specified for non-CHAR data

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, spring-mvc, teradata

I am passing a date parameter using the "?" notation at run time using Eclipse and Java to the following SQL below. However, when the below code is executed it breaks with the following error:

> [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.35] [Error 3536] [SQLState
> HY000] UPPERCASE or CASESPECIFIC specified for non-CHAR data.

This error only appears when I try to pass the date on rumtime using the ? notation. If I hard code the date in my SQL below and run it through eclipse it runs fine. Can anyone please suggest a fix?

```sql
SELECT 
  TO_DATE (TRIM(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM cast(? as varchar(100)) )) || '-0' || 
  TRIM(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM S1.birthday)) ||'-'|| 
  TRIM(EXTRACT (DAY FROM S1.birthday)) ,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS start_Date 
FROM STAFF S1 
WHERE S1.TEAMID IN (4)  
AND (start_date between date-10 and date) 
AND birthday IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think in your `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM cast(? as varchar(100))` expression, you need to use `EXTRACT` with a `DATE` and not a `VARCHAR`.  What if you remove the `CAST` and just pass in a value like `DATE '2010-01-01'` at runtime?

Comment: @ravioli even if I use (YEAR FROM ? ) with the ? being passed in as a date on runtime it gives the same error. Strangely though, if I hard code a date like '2010-01-01' it works. But I can't hard code the date as I need it to be passed on runtime.

Comment: You could optimize it by using the trick that DATE is stored as INT with the year just decreased by 1900.
just try: SELECT DATE (INT); and remember this year 2020 minus 1900 is 120.
With this try:
select '1983-03-06' (DATE) as birthday
      ,birthday mod 10000 as birthday_mmdd
      ,2020 as input_year
      ,((input_year-1900)*10000 + birthday_mmdd) (DATE) as birthday_thisYear;

The last line does the same like your SQL but less CAST, EXTRACT, TRIM.

Comment: What happens if you pass just the year as your parameter?  I'd also suggest trying to upgrade your  JDBC driver, that's probably 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Just passing the Year try this SQL:

`SELECT (S1.birthday MOD 10000 + ((? (INT))-1900)*10000) (DATE) as start_date FROM STAFF S1  WHERE S1.TEAMID IN (4)   AND (start_date between date-10 and date)  AND birthday IS NOT NULL ;`

Missing the Eclipse/Java Wrapper, I'm not 100% sure. But the SQL itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, you try to extract a year from a VarChar instead of a date. But even if fixed it will fail whenever there's a birthdate of Feb 29.

Seems you want to calculate the birthday within the current year and then filter based on this like *who had birthday within the the last week*. The easiest way to do this is to calculate the age like

```
cast(months_between (current_date, birthday)/12 as int)
```

and add that number of years to the birthdate

```
add_months(birthday, cast(months_between(current_date, birthday)/12 as int)*12) as birthday_this_year
```

Then you can filter

```
where birthday_this_year between current_date -10 and current_date
```